# Nginx looking for file rather than endpoint?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have nginx & docker-compose setup with the following nginx config file, here `api` and `kibana` are docker containers which are running on ports 8080 and 5601 respectively

```
user nobody;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events
{
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http
{
  server
  {
    listen 80;
    server_name my-domain.com www.my-domain.com;
    server_tokens off;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
  }

  server
  {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name my-domain.com www.my-domain.com;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/all/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/all/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location ^~ /
    {
      proxy_pass http://api:8080/;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }

    location ^~ /monitoring
    {
      proxy_pass http://kibana:5601/;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      rewrite /monitoring/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    }
  }
}
```

All of my containers are up and running and everything seems fine but when i visit `https://my-domain.com` i get back `This site can’t be reached` and if i go to the non-secure `http://my-domain.com/` i get nginx 404 error with the following log in the container

```
[error] 17#17: *13 open() "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.456.789.101, server: my-domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "my-domain.com
```

Why is it looking for a file? Is there something wrong with my nginx config? pls help

Comment: Config File was consumed? check with ```nginx -T``` the active config. What is the supposed index file? Should be given with ```index index.php```or whatever in http-block

Comment: Yes, config file is being used, I did `nginx -t` got syntax is ok then checked the file at the path that's shown and it had same configuration. There's not supposed to be any index file, i just want to reverse proxy it to my node api and kibana server

Answer (score 0):

Found it! ‍♂️ it should've been

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

instead of

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

Edit:
Apparently i also had to stop docker containers after running it for the first time and start again to get it to work